# Java sorting parallel arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, parallel-processing

I have to sort a database of 1 string array and 2 int arrays. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void sortDatabase(int numRecords, String[] sDeptArr, 
              int[] iCourseNumArr, int[] iEnrollmentArr)
   {
       int length = sDeptArr.length;
       for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++)
       {
           int iPosMin = i;
           for(int j=i+1; j<length; j++)
           {
               if(sDeptArr[j].compareTo(sDeptArr[iPosMin]) == 0)
                   iPosMin = j;
               else if(sDeptArr[j].equals(sDeptArr[iPosMin]) && iCourseNumArr[j] < iCourseNumArr[iPosMin])
                   iPosMin = j;
           }
       }
   }
```

I have yet to test it because the entire program is not done but does this look like it is going in the right direction? I want to sort the database in alphabetical order by name first, then if the names are the same, use the course number to sort.

Comment: Any reasons, you aren't using sql to do it?

Comment: Because I have to do it in java.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO your direction is not optimal.
The best way I know is to create new data structure

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
    private String sDeptArr;
    private int iCourseNumArr;
    private int iEnrollmentArr;

    public int compareTo(Data other) {
    // your implementation
    }
}
```

Now create an array or collection of Data:

```
List<Data>
Data[]
```

Now use `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Not that simple. We have to use java and do it the way that the professor said using a method and using something like that seen above in my original post.