# How to compare and rearrange an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three different arraylists and want to rearrange them. Bob is paired up with 1 and 4, tom is paired up with 4 and 3, and so on.

```
a = [1,    4,   2,    6,    4]
b = [4,    3,   3,    6,    7]
c = [bob, tom, ross, alex, jim]
```

ArrayList "a" should be from highest to lowest and if two numbers are the same you would have to compare out of the two who had the highest number in ArrayList "b". For example, in ArrayList "a", we have 4 and 4 so we need to go to compare 3 and 7 in ArrayList "b" and rearrange them based on the higher. Now, if the two numbers are also the same in ArrayList "b" we would go to ArrayList "c" and order the two alphabetically. These are just random numbers I type in. I thought about creating another ArrayList like

```
{{1,4,bob},{4,3,tom},{2,3,ross},...}
```

However, I have no idea how to  compare the array  like comparing 1 with  4 or bob with tom.

Comment: What code have you attempted?  Please show it.  But it seems like you're just supposed to take the elements in the order you've given.

Comment: What does *rearrange them based on the higher* mean? Rearrange what with what? What output do you expect?

Comment: This is a pattern called _parallel arrays_, and you should replace it with classes. Then you can use `Collections.sort` with a comparator.

Comment: The question is closed due to having answer in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293146/java-sorting-parallel-arrays 
however it does not have an accepted answer, two questions with no accepted answers, so we may see same question again

Answer (score 4):

When you have elements that are related to each other it is best (imo) to put them in a class or record. I chose a `record` for ease of coding.

```
List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 4, 2, 6, 4);
List<Integer> b = List.of(4, 3, 3, 6, 7);
List<String> c = List.of("bob", "tom", "ross", "alex", "jim");


record Info(int a, int b, String name) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s, %s, %s}", name, a, b);
    }
}
```

- Now as the Lists are indexed by a stream of ints use the `Info` constructor to create instances of that record.
- Then sort using a comparator.  This sorts first on `a` and if equal, then on `b`, in reversed order as requested, and if equal, finally on the name in alphabetical order.
- Then the records are returned in `List<Info>`.

```
List<Info> info = IntStream.range(0, a.size())

        // create the new object here
        .mapToObj(i -> new Info(a.get(i), b.get(i), c.get(i)))

        //and now sort those objects based on the required criteria
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Info::a)
                .thenComparing(Info::b).reversed()
                .thenComparing(Info::name))

        //and return in a list.
        .toList();

for (Info in : info) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

Prints

```
{alex, 6, 6}
{jim, 4, 7}
{tom, 4, 3}
{ross, 2, 3}
{bob, 1, 4}
```

Comment: very nice language usage ! this is why we like SO

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it more clearly separated the steps of "create a proper object out of the parallel arrays" and "sort the objects based on custom criteria".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  I thought I had sufficiently done that.  However, I added some comments in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  Make a single data structure:

```
class Datum implements Comparable {
    final int a;
    final int b;
    final String c;

    public Datum(int a, int b, String c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Datum other = (Datum) o;
        int diff = Integer.compare(a, b);
        if (diff == 0) {
            diff = Integer.compare(a, b);
            if (diff == 0) { // b is also same, so check c
                diff = c.compareTo(other.c);
            }
        }
        return diff;
    }
}
```

Put everything into a single List and sort it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 4, 2, 6, 4);
    List<Integer> b = List.of(4, 3, 3, 6, 7);
    List<String>  c = List.of("bob","tom","ross","alex","jim");
    
    int numItems = a.size();
    List<Datum> data = new ArrayList<>(numItems);
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        data.add(new Datum(a.get(i), b.get(i), c.get(i)));
    }
    Collections.sort(data);
    //  Now you have the data in the order you want... 
}
```

Presumably the data has some meaning and the names `a`,`b`,`c`, and `Datum` can be made more meaningful.

Comment: This comparator can create an overflow. You can use existing library functions as Integer.compare(...)

Comment: Good point.. I'mm guessing it likely wouldn't be a problem for the expected data, but I've updated the code just for general correctness.

Answer (score 0):

**-- Works For Java 8 + --**

You can write a custom sort for the index array that you can create.

I mean, you need to sort the index array of arrays, rather than the arrays itself first, then you can arrange them based on the sorted index array.

Here is the code for it:

```
  public void customSorts() {
    List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 4, 2, 6, 4);
    List<Integer> b = List.of(4, 3, 3, 6, 7);
    List<String>  c = List.of("bob","tom","ross","alex","jim");
    Integer indexes[] = new Integer[] {0,1,2,3,4};
    
    Arrays.sort(indexes, (i1, i2) -> {
      int resultOfA = Integer.compare(a.get(i2),a.get(i1));
      if(resultOfA != 0) return resultOfA;
       
      int resultOfB = Integer.compare(b.get(i2),b.get(i1));
      if(resultOfB != 0)  return resultOfB; 
      
      return c.get(i1).compareTo(c.get(i2));   
    });
    
    List<Integer> aRearranged = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> bRearranged = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String>  cRearranged = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i:indexes)  {
       aRearranged.add(a.get(i));
       bRearranged.add(b.get(i));
       cRearranged.add(c.get(i));
    }
      
    // Print them
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aRearranged.toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bRearranged.toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cRearranged.toArray()));
    // Print indexes
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexes));
    
}
```

Prints

```
[6, 4, 4, 2, 1]
[6, 7, 3, 3, 4]
[alex, jim, tom, ross, bob]
[3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the following sort order.

1. a : descending order
2. b : descending order
3. c : ascending order

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4);
    List<Integer> b = List.of(4, 3, 3, 6, 7, 3);
    List<String> c = List.of("bob", "tom", "ross", "alex", "jim", "alan");

    record Item(int a, int b, String c) {
        @Override public String toString() {
            return String.format("{%s, %s, %s}", a, b, c);
        }
    }

    List<Item> output = IntStream.range(0, a.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new Item(a.get(i), b.get(i), c.get(i)))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::a)
            .thenComparing(Item::b).reversed()
            .thenComparing(Item::c))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

output:

```
[{6, 6, alex}, {4, 7, jim}, {4, 3, alan}, {4, 3, tom}, {2, 3, ross}, {1, 4, bob}]
```